# Ag-grid style sheet file is loaded but does not work

Tags: ag-grid

I used ag-grid a few times before and each time it works with no probs, but now for no reason the css is not working I use these links for css :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-themealpine.css">
```

I didn't get any error on my page and the links are valid.
The css file was loaded on my page and I can see it using F12.
What should I check next ? how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `-` between `theme` and `alpine` in `ag-themealpine.css`in the second link tag.

Replace that link tag with the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css" />
```

See this implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/2lI1IY8A8qVXJiwl?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).